# Apply Conditional Formatting VBA to All workbook Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am very new to this, I am making conditional formatting to highlight numbers above the average of all values in a row.

I need to apply this formatting to all rows in all sheets in the workbook.

From what I've collected this is what I've got:

```
 Sub AllSheets()
         Dim ws As Worksheet
         For Each ws In Worksheets
            Range("A1:S1").Copy
            For Each r In Selection.Rows
            r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
            Next r
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next ws
 End Sub
```

But when I run this, it only applies it to the active selected cells. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the `Range()` being used is actually the range in the `ws`.  Otherwise, it just runs on the Activesheet.

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Range("A1:S1").Copy 
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
         r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Next r
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next ws

End Sub
```

But, does this work?  It's a little "tighter", mainly I'm trying to [avoid using `.Selection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Range("A1:S1").Copy ' Or replace this with actual range, not just `Selection`
    For Each r In ws.Range("A1:S1").Rows
         r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Next r
Next ws

End Sub
```

Edit: just realized...Why even use the `For each r` loop, since you're only using one row anyways?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to apply this formatting to all rows in all sheets in the
>   workbook.

Indeed, it takes practice to "know how to ask the right question". Once you can do that, a quick search:

Cycle through worksheets vba

```
  Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook